# solr spellchecker with phonetic filters

Tags: solr

I have tried to use phonetic filters for the field that indexes spellings (**solr 1.4**). Following is the fieldType configuration in **schema.xml**

```
<fieldType name="textSpell" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" omitNorms="false">
        <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.PhoneticFilterFactory" encoder="DoubleMetaphone" inject="true"/>
        </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

However i do not see any difference when phonetic filter is used (size of the spellchecker index remains same and no difference in corrections). Are phonetic filters ignored when used with spellCheckers or is there any issue with my configuration?

**solrConfig.xml**

```
  <requestHandler name="standard" class="solr.SearchHandler" default="true">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.collate">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.onlyMorePopular">false</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.extendedResults">true</str>
        <str name="spellcheck.count">5</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
        <str>spellcheck</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>

  <searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">
    <str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>
    <lst name="spellchecker">
      <str name="name">default</str>
      <str name="field">loc_name_texts</str>
      <str name="spellcheckIndexDir">./spellchecker</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">true</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

**UPDATE:**
I have initially configured filters wrongly so WhitespaceTokenizer was being used all the time. I have corrected that now.. However, when phonetic filters are used, solr returns the transformed data (metaphones). Is there anyway to get the content stored as part of the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

phonetic filters in solr are **not** used to return a corrected suggestion. they are used to match a document even if the query is spelled wrong.

the spellcheck component is used to return a corrected suggestion, but works only on fields with whole words, not phonetic fields.

Answer (score 0):

try changing 'spellcheck' element to this

```
    <bool name="spellcheck">true</bool>
```